# How to format and display flatten results?

Tags: html, arrays, filter, twig

please Help me with this question.

I need display results flatten(agroupated) by key.

Actualy mys twig code is:

The perfect Result is:

```
<dt class='detail'>Color(s):</dt><dd>Blue, Red, Orange</dd><br><br>
<dt class='detail'>Style(s):</dt><dd>Old, Japanese</dd><br><br>
```

My test:

```
{{ product_properties(product.properties, "<dt class='detail'>{key}:</dt><dd>{value}</dd><br><br>") }}
```

Results:

```
<dt class='detail'>Color(s):</dt><dd>Blue</dd><br><br>
<dt class='detail'>Style(s):</dt><dd>Old</dd><br><br>
<dt class='detail'>Color(s):</dt><dd>Red</dd><br><br>
<dt class='detail'>Style(s):</dt><dd>Japanese</dd><br><br>
<dt class='detail'>Color(s):</dt><dd>Orange</dd><br><br>
```

Comment: unclear, we don't know `product_properties` nor your input data

Comment: This clarify for you?

    {% if product.properties|count > 0 %}
{{ product_properties(product.properties, "<dt class='detail'>{key}:</dt><dd>{value}</dd><br><br>") }}
    {% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `product.properties` object is like this:

```js
productProperties = {
    color: ['blue', 'red', 'orange'],
    style: ['old', 'japanese']
}
```

But `product_properties` function is looping through each element of the property of the object.

Consider translating your product object to other that concatenates all the values of each property:

```js
function concatProps(productProperties) {
    return {
        color: productProperties.color.join(),
        style: productProperties.style.join()
    }
}
```

And then, do:

```html
{{ product_properties(concatProps(product.properties), "<dt class='detail'>{key}:</dt><dd>{value}</dd><br><br>") }}
```

Hope it helps. I can´t do more without more details.